# Optimizing order of WHERE clause evaluation in DB2

Tags: sql, optimization, db2, query-optimization, where-clause

I'm working with two extremely large tables (A is ~20E6 rows, B is ~65E3 rows) and I have very elaborate where clauses to get just the items I need. One thing that could speed it up is to first evaluate the date the entry was created (info goes back 10+ years, only need last 3 years); this would eliminate most of the data before doing expensive string processing. Is there a way to force the evaluation of the `WHERE date > cutoff_date` to happen before the other clauses?

Here is what my query looks like.

```
SELECT A.C1, A.C2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN B.C1 = '[condition 1]' OR ...  [condition n] THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    AS SUM_OF_B_C1, ... [other sums]
FROM DB.TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN DB.TABLE_B AS B ON B.COMMON_COL = A.COMMON_COL
WHERE B.DATE > DATE('[cutoff date]')
    AND [complex substr conditions]
    AND NOT [other complex string conditions]
GROUP BY A.C1, A.C2
```

One problem, is that I only have read permission for the DB. Looking through Control Center, it seems that there is no index on either tables A or B, so that optimization route is out.

Any help you could provide would be great; my small test queries are taking about 5 minutes and in product queries will be about 20 times larger.

Comment: If there is no index it is going to have to scan the entire table to check the dates. At best you could perhaps subquery the date potion but really - no indexes = you are not going to optimize a scan.

Comment: I don't mind it scanning the whole table for dates, that's pretty quick. I just don't want it to scan the whole table doing really heavy text processing. Subqueries could help though? I'm really new to DB2/SQL (about a week) and would love if you could point me toward what you mean.

Comment: It might also help if you placed some of the other `where` clause conditions in the `join` criteria; at the moment, your query is getting everything from `b` that matches on a common column, then throwing it out if it's <= the cutoff date - add this as part of the `left join` condition, and see if that helps (DB2's optimizer will muck with join criteria and ordering, but this should provide a helpful hint to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to out-think modern query optimizers isn't usually very productive. I think you should spend your time doing two other things.

1. Find out what business process lets you get indexes created on the
   columns that should have indexes.
2. Learn how to run and interpret the output of `EXPLAIN PLAN`. This
   lets you approach management with numbers that show your code is
   dead slow not because you're incompetent, but because <del>they
   are</del> DB2 is forced to do table scans all over the place.

Tables that have *no* indexes at all are often generated by programs either to simplify querying and reporting or to reduce the load on the main database server. Find out who's responsible for *those* programs. Befriend them. Buy them a pizza. Think "social engineering".

Comment: I think you're quite right. I shouldn't have to battle the system; it should be setup to work properly.

Comment: Right. And *you* can't set it up to work properly, either. So it's  management's job. (Although, as a practical matter, it's common to have to work around management.) If you have a good relationship with your immediate supervisor, start there. If not, go back to pizza and social engineering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WITH clause in your [SELECT statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000879.html):

```
WITH
B2(col1, col2, ... ) AS (
    SELECT col1, col2, ...
    FROM DB.TABLE_B AS B
    WHERE B.DATE > DATE('[cutoff date]')
)
SELECT A.C1, A.C2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN B2.C1 = '[condition 1]' OR ...  [condition n] THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    AS SUM_OF_B_C1, ... [other sums]
FROM DB.TABLE_A A LEFT JOIN B2 ON B2.COMMON_COL = A.COMMON_COL
WHERE 
    AND [complex substr conditions]
    AND NOT [other complex string conditions]
GROUP BY A.C1, A.C2
```